# Align navbar on bottom of screen - Boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to align the footer (Bootstrap navbar) on bottom of screen (Browser area), without using fixed navbar.
if the content height less than the screen height , show "navbar" on bottom, otherwise use scrollbars normally.

I tried with navabr-fixed-bottom, but it always shows the navabar, even if the content height is larger.

```
<!-- FOOTER -->
<div class="visible-desktop navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
 ...
</div>
```

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: Why negative rating? Very legit question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Bootstrap has this kind of build in functionality, here is simple trick which may be helpful, but it requires you do have fixed height of the navbar.

[How to keep footers at the bottom of the page](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)